# amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused

Tags: active-directory, ssh, connection

I know it's multi-duplicate topic but I can't comment in other topic.

I tried every solution and I still can't connect with my ec2 instance.

I even checked my pem file

```
openssl pkcs8 -in ~/.ssh/macbook-pro-15.pem -inform PEM -outform DER -topk8 -nocrypt
```

which is correct.

I also tried to `ping` ec2 instance, but I think `ping` is blocked by default.

```
92 bytes from 10.128.128.128: Communication prohibited by filter
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
 4  5  00 5400 8727   0 0000  40  01 5c3a 10.6.67.47  35.158.38.117
```

Comment: What security group rules are applied to your instance? What do your client logs say?

Answer (score 0):

In your EC2 Security Group make sure you enable icmp4 from your public IP address, that way you will be able to ping your instance, you can find more information [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html).

In order to connect to the instance you need to use something like...

```
ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Of course you have to change the example with the actual data.

You have also yo check permissions on the pem file, It should have a 0400 mask.

If you still have issues to connect, please execute an ssh connection with a higher level of verbosity:

```
ssh -vvv -i /path/my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```